# How to translate an echo in PHP with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a HTML site and I made a toggle that changes the language without refreshing the page (with Javascript), **I just assign an ID and that's it, as you can see here:**

```
var strings = {
    espanol: {
        //PRINCIPAL//
        lang: "<i class='fa-duotone fa-earth-americas fa-lg'></i> Idioma",
    },
    english: {
        //PRINCIPAL//
        lang: "<i class='fa-duotone fa-earth-americas fa-lg'></i> Language",
    }
}

$( ".espanol" ).on( "click", function() {
    // update to espanol
    localizeStrings('espanol');
});
$( ".english" ).on( "click", function() {
    // update to english
    localizeStrings('english');
});

// default language 
var Lang = "espanol";

// localize with default language
localizeStrings(Lang);

// update selected language   
function localizeStrings(strLang) {
    $(strings[strLang]).each(function(key, lang){
        $.each(lang, function(id, string) {
            $("#"+id).html(string);
        });
    });
}
```

To well there, but a part of my web, returns to a  an echo of a PHP file.

So I have no idea how to translate it, could you help me? I am new to this.

**Normal (HTML) translation:**

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-mdb-toggle="dropdown" id="lang" aria-expanded="false"></a>
```

**PHP echo that I want to translate:**

```
echo '{"error":-1, "msg":"<font color=#B23CFD><b>Unknown</b></font> | '.$text2.' -YES"}';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two things you can do:
1. Translate on server-side. This means you´ll have to pass the selected language to you PHP file somehow, for instance put it into a header when calling the PHP file, then read the header and translate it.



2. Translate on client side. This sounds bad but if it´s only one instance of let´s say "unknown" that you want to translate then simply translate it using JavaScript after you receive the response from the PHP file. 
It really depents on the tools you´re using but with AJAX that should be pretty easy using the success handler

Comment: @FabianZimbalev Thank you very much for the idea! Since they are simple words, it suits me more on the client side.
How can I adapt the existing configuration (that I put in the post) to be able to translate it when I receive the response in PHP?
I am very new to this and the only thing I master is HTML and CSS :(